# how do you see the milliseconds of date type column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to retrieve miliseconds data from the a column. The column is

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP  DATE is a date type.
```

I need to be able to do this:

```
to_char(collection_timestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS.FF') COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I need to be able to see the miliseconds section as well. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well: You should use `timestamp`data-type instead of `date`data-type if you want timestamps: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm

Comment: @evillive, not my db, I was just curious whether it is doable. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The DATE type is only accurate down to the second - it does not maintain fractions of a second. For greater accuracy you should use the TIMESTAMP type.